# Why does a copyright on a website include?

Tags: website-design, copywriting

I'm designing a new site and I take ideas from sites but mix them around a little bit. All companies have the copyright on their footer, what does the copyright include?

**For example, can you copyright the flow and structure of a site? Or, just the concept and logo?**

Comment: This is a legal question, not a UX question

Comment: @Midas It's a mixture of a UX and legal question. What parts of design can be copyrighted? In the past, UX has answered legal and UX questions and they been very well received: [here](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/51556/why-do-movie-posters-use-credit-fonts-that-are-hard-to-read/51563#51563), [here](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/85465/why-let-users-deactivate-delete-account/85466#85466) and [here](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/34305/if-nobody-reads-privacy-policies-or-terms-and-conditions-why-not-change-them).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a legal question

Comment: @Devin Read my comment to Midas. If you close my question, you should close every other legal UX question. It's not fair to pick and choose...

Comment: @CødePlay This is a purely legal question. The other examples you cited were UX questions that had a legal aspect to their answers. The question you are asking here is about what is legally enforceable for a website. To answer your questions: you can copyright the business name, the text and image content of the site (including logos and the specific application of layout), but, as far as I am aware, not the general structure or flow.